# libgdx: How do i get the result of an orthographic camera through another orthographic camera?

Tags: libgdx

I would like to have a TV screen on my stage. I have a master scene containing the TV screen and some other things (some sprites) and the scene corresponding to what I want to render in the TV.

So I would like to render the TV scene through an OrthographicCamera and then put the result in something like a sprite which can then be rendered through the master orthographic camera, how to do that?

I know that one can use multiple camera in multiple viewports but these are directly rendered on the pixels of my computer screen.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Is this for 3D or 2D?

Comment: I'm using 2D features only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by rendering the scene from the perspective of a screen camera to a `FrameBuffer` and then taking the `TextureRegion` from the `FrameBuffer` and rendering that to screen and then render the scene again.

For example:

[image]

In the above example the cyan rect shows what the in-scene camera sees, and this is rendered to the grey box, it is possible to move both the scene camera and the main camera independentely.

By creating and grabbing the `TextureRegion` from a `FrameBuffer`

```
screenFrameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),true);
screenTexture = new TextureRegion(screenFrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture());
screenTexture.flip(false, true);
```

all render calls can be made to affect only the `screenFrameBuffer` by calling `screenFrameBuffer.begin()`, after `screenFrameBuffer.end()` is called the next draw call will again affect the actual screen/window.

So in in the `render` method you can first draw your scene to the `FrameBuffer`

```
screenFrameBuffer.begin();
renderScene(screenCamera, Color.DARK_GRAY);
screenFrameBuffer.end();
```

And then draw it again, followed by the "*screen*" as a sprite:

```
renderScene(sceneCamera, Color.BLACK);

batch.setProjectionMatrix(sceneCamera.combined);
batch.begin();
batch.draw(screenTexture, -sceneCamera.viewportWidth / 2.0f,-sceneCamera.viewportHeight / 2.0f,0,0,screenCamera.viewportWidth,screenCamera.viewportHeight,1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
batch.end();
```

Complete source code for the gif above is:

```
package com.bornander.sandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.RandomXS128;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {

    public static class Ball {
        public Vector2 position = new Vector2();
        public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
        public float size = 1.0f;
        public Color color = new Color();

        public void render(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer) {
            shapeRenderer.setColor(color);
            shapeRenderer.circle(position.x, position.y, size, 16);
        }

        public void update() {
            position.x += velocity.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            position.y += velocity.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        }
    }

    static RandomXS128 rnd = new RandomXS128();

    OrthographicCamera sceneCamera;
    OrthographicCamera screenCamera;
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    FrameBuffer screenFrameBuffer;
    TextureRegion screenTexture;
    Ball[] balls;

    private static float rnd(float min, float max) {
        return min + rnd.nextFloat() * (max - min);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        float aspectRatio = (float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        sceneCamera = new OrthographicCamera(100.0f, 100.0f / aspectRatio);
        screenCamera = new OrthographicCamera(32.0f, 32.0f / aspectRatio);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        screenFrameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),true);
        screenTexture = new TextureRegion(screenFrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture());
        screenTexture.flip(false, true);
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        balls = new Ball[128];
        for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; ++i) {
            balls[i] = new Ball();
            balls[i].position.set(0, 0);
            balls[i].velocity.set(rnd(-4, 4), rnd(-4, 4));
            balls[i].size = rnd(1, 1);
            balls[i].color.set(rnd(0.5f, 1.0f), rnd(0.5f, 1.0f), rnd(0.5f, 1.0f), 1.0f);
        }
    }

    private void renderScene(Camera camera, Color background) {
        camera.update();
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(background.r, background.g, background.b, background.a);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; ++i) {
            balls[i].render(shapeRenderer);
        }
        shapeRenderer.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        float cs = 8.0f;
        for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; ++i)
            balls[i].update();

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
            sceneCamera.position.x -= cs * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))
            sceneCamera.position.x += cs * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
            sceneCamera.position.y -= cs * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN))
            sceneCamera.position.y += cs * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))
            screenCamera.position.x -= cs * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
            screenCamera.position.x += cs * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W))
            screenCamera.position.y -= cs * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))
            screenCamera.position.y += cs * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        // Render to framebuffer, clear the background to DARK_GRAY
        screenFrameBuffer.begin();
        renderScene(screenCamera, Color.DARK_GRAY);
        screenFrameBuffer.end();

        // Render to window/screen, clear backgroun to BLACK
        renderScene(sceneCamera, Color.BLACK);

        // Draw the framebuffer's texture as a sprite using a normal SpriteBatch
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(sceneCamera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(screenTexture, -sceneCamera.viewportWidth / 2.0f,-sceneCamera.viewportHeight / 2.0f,0,0,screenCamera.viewportWidth,screenCamera.viewportHeight,1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        batch.end();

        // This just draws the outline of what the screen camera looks at
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(sceneCamera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        shapeRenderer.rect(
                screenCamera.position.x - screenCamera.viewportWidth / 2.0f,
                screenCamera.position.y - screenCamera.viewportHeight / 2.0f,
                screenCamera.viewportWidth,
                screenCamera.viewportHeight

        );
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```